# After updating to Ubuntu 22.04 | Help pane in Spyder does not work, Spyder has loading errors

Tags: 22.04, spyder

When I use <cntl>+i to ask for help on a function, the help pane flashes briefly and then returns to blank.
It seems the editor retains the connection, but the content is not written out to the pane.

When running spyder from the command line the following errors appear:

```
~$ spyder
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /home/xyz/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /home/xyz/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
link image0 hasn't been detected!
```

The required driver file is not on the HDD:

```
~$ locate GLIBCXX_3.4.29
~$
```

Comment: Then you should describe **how** you installed `spyder`. It looks like you've installed from an old ppa/repository.

Comment: @kanehekili - spyder was installed as part of anaconda: '~$ which spyder
/home/ant/anaconda3/bin/spyder
'

Comment: 'spyder                    5.1.5            py39h06a4308_1  
spyder-kernels            2.1.3            py39h06a4308_0 '